# Tracking Google OAuth2 token changes

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth

I have a JavaScript app that uses Google OAuth2 for login and then sends the token to the web server to authenticate the email address against our database to validate the user. I currently have the server verifying the token with Google on every request (AJAX) to ensure that the user is still valid (in case we need to

However, after about an hour the token expires and changes and no longer authenticates on the back-end. After digging around I found that I could get the new current token by accessing:

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.ha.value.B.id_token
```

but that looks somewhat obfuscated and unreliable (e.g. if Google changes this in the future). Is there any official way to get the new token, either by an API call or event listener?

(the "duplicate" question has the wrong answer - the comments by Jarosław Gomułka below are correct)

Comment: You should use currentUser.listen(callback) (see https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners and https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthcurrentuserlistenwzxhzdk58listenerwzxhzdk59). Listen will be called on every googleUser change. To get id_token in callback call googleUser.getAuthResult().id_token.

Comment: I was wondering about that but I couldn't find any documentation that confirmed under what circumstances the userChanged event was fired. And testing this is annoying because it means waiting an hour for the token to expire (unless there's another way to shorten the life-span of a token?).

Comment: Sorry I meant the "currentUser event"

Comment: @JarosławGomułka it's getAuthResponse() :)

Comment: Yes, it's getAuthResponse(). You can call auth2.disconnect() or auth2.signOut() and re-signin to test it.